# Исходники python QToolBar и QPushButton

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, pyqt

Подскажите, где можно скачать исходные коды `QToolBar.py` и `QPushButton.py`?

Хочу разобраться как работает... нашел https://antonz.ru/python-sources/ но самой ссылки на github разработчика не вижу.

### Дополнительный вопрос 1:

Пример:

```
    self.TOOLBAR = QtWidgets.QToolBar(MainWindow)
    self.TOOLBAR.setEnabled(False)

    self.TOOLBAR.setStyleSheet("SETSTYLESHEET")
    self.TOOLBAR.setMovable(False)
    self.TOOLBAR.setAllowedAreas(QtCore.Qt.NoToolBarArea)
    self.TOOLBAR.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
    self.TOOLBAR.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonIconOnly)
    self.TOOLBAR.setFloatable(False)
    self.TOOLBAR.setObjectName("TOOLBAR")
```

Xочу чтобы было приблизительно так:

```
    self.TOOLBAR = KWidgets.KToolBar(MainWindow)
    self.TOOLBAR.setEnabled(False)

    self.TOOLBAR.setStyleSheet("SETSTYLESHEET")
    self.TOOLBAR.setMovable(False)
    self.TOOLBAR.setAllowedAreas(QtCore.Qt.NoToolBarArea)
    self.TOOLBAR.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
    self.TOOLBAR.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonIconOnly)
    self.TOOLBAR.setFloatable(False)
    self.TOOLBAR.setObjectName("TOOLBAR")
```

(как результат должно быть наследование KToolBar из QToolBar и присвоение определенных параметров)

### Дополнительный вопрос 2:

В файле Main(вызов):

```
self.toolbar = KWidgets.KToolBar(self.mwidget)

# тут нужно вызвать setIconSize
```

В файле KWidgets.py:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QToolBar

class KToolBar(QToolBar):
    pass

    # тут нужно вызвать setStyleSheet
```

Comment: Вы ведь в курсе, что эти классы под капотом работают с соответствующими Qt c++ классами (например https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qtoolbar.cpp?h=dev#n520)? :) Или вам все-таки интересны исходники оберток QToolBar.py и QPushButton.py?

Comment: хочу сделать аналог QToolBar со своими параметрами. и чтобы аналогично было использование параметров setStyleSheet и пр...

Comment: ну так создайте своего наследника от QToolBar с нужной логикой. Если вообще с нуля делать, то создавайте наследника от QWidget

Comment: добавил доп вопрос.

Comment: Кроме того, что вы поменяли название пакета/модуля и класса разницы не вижу... Зачем это нужно? В чем смысл?

Comment: я думаю, что исходники вам не помогут. Для начала почитайте https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QToolBar.html?highlight=qtoolbar#qtoolbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил пример наследования для создания своей реализации виджета:

**KToolBar.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QToolBar

class KToolBar(QToolBar):
    pass
```

---

**UPD.**

Еще раз, наследование это полное "копирование" родителя с возможностью внесения изменений: переопределение методов родителя, создание новых, поэтому все-тоже самое, что для **QToolBar**:

```
class KToolBar(QToolBar):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setStyleSheet(...
```

И

```
self.toolbar = KWidgets.KToolBar(self.mwidget)
self.toolbar.setIconSize(...
```

Comment: а как тогда будет выглядеть вызов данного KToolBar? и как будет прописано использование setStyleSheet в файле KToolBar.py ?

Comment: Также как у `QToolBar`: `self.TOOLBAR = KToolBar(MainWindow)`. Чтобы из KWidgets брать KToolBar нужно создать пакет KWidgets и в него поместить KToolBar.py

Comment: добавил доп вопрос 2.

Comment: Вылетает ошибка:   in init self.toolbar = KWidgets.KToolBar(self.mwidget) TypeError: __init__() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 were given   что не так? родитель места вызова     def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.secondWin = None

Comment: Извиняюсь, опечатался поправил ответ )